# Get the last run_at for a DelayedJob in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using Rails Delayed Job to enqueue jobs to run at a specific time. Is it possible to know the timestamp for when a particular Delayed Job is last run?

Answer (score 0):

You need to query for the job by some identifier. Your jobs are saved into a delayed_jobs table and the text field called 'handler' is where you can find them.
From delayed_job documenatation:

```
 table.text :handler # YAML-encoded string of the object
```

that will do work
So to query them you can do

```
Delayed::Job.where("handler LIKE '%name: #{name}%'")
```

I don't know exactly what unique name you have there, 'name' is made up and might not work. Easiest think is to look in the database. Possibly the job's class name is saved and you can query by that.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no timestamp in the database already, you can use a callback for the job: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#callbacks
You could create a new model called JobLogs for example and save the data there.

As you can see from the documentation you can use the callback `after_perform :save_time` in your job and then define the method somewhat like this:

```
def save_time
  JobLog.create(last_run: Time.now.utc)
end
```